# Angular ng-swipe with youtube iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube, angularjs-ng-touch

I'm trying to build simply slider with images and youtube videos. I want make it works fine on touch devices, so I want to use `ng-swipe-*` from angular's `ngTouch` module. Unfortunately swipe doesn't work over youtube's iframe. I tried to set lower `z-index: -10;`, but then I cannot play the video.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

There is a snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch']);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.msg = function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  }
});
```

```css
.ok {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl" ng-swipe-right="msg('right')" ng-swipe-left="msg('left')">
    <div class="ok">swipe works here</div>
    <div>
      <iframe width="300" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(the best way to test it, is to run it in Chrome developer console and emulate on touch device)

Comment: This seems to be the same issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180672/youtube-cannot-swipe-past-iframe-in-carousel-slider - where they recommend using a image in place of the iframe at the start. Is this a viable solution?

Comment: @jjbskir, hmm, I could use image with custom play button, and replace the video and the image on click with ng-show, but if user pause the video he won't be able to swipe again. Also I don't know if it is possible to start the video with custom button ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty hacky workaround: using **two** overlay divs, set to the right and the left of the player allows the user to play and pause, and setting the height to 80% allows them to use the menu on the bottom. This is not perfect, but it kind of works!

***Note 1: It's kind of buggy if you play it here, so I'm adding a codepen:*** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGjwYZ

*Second version, a little bit more bloated but with more area coverage: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxzXxB*

*Note 2: I used a transparent background on the divs for demonstrational purposes.*

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch']);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.msg = function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  }
});
```

```css
.ok {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl" ng-swipe-right="msg('right')" ng-swipe-left="msg('left')">
    <div class="ok">swipe works here</div>
    <div style="position:relative; height:200px; width:300px;">
        <iframe style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:10;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ"></iframe>
        <div style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);height:80%;width:40%;left:0;position:absolute;z-index:20;"></div>
      <div style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);height:80%;width:40%;right:0;position:absolute;z-index:20;"></div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. If no one posts better answer I will accept this one.

Comment: Updated with a more exaggerate version.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you don't have control of events within the iframe, so can't tell when the user swipes over that area. The work around I suggest is to replace the iframe with a image placeholder while not watching. In order to do this use [YouTube's Iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en) to keep track of video events. When the video goes from play to pause we will hide the video and show the image. [Here is a demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/3vNzkblb4JRBG9pIJY2r?p=preview).

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl" ng-swipe-right="msg($event, 'right')" ng-swipe-left="msg($event, 'left')">
    <div id="player"></div>
    <img id="player-cover" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/M7lc1UVf-VE/hqdefault.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

On initiation it hides the video. When ever the image is clicked it shows and plays the video. When the video goes from paused to play `onPlayerStateChange` handles toggling the image and video. Every time the swiping event gets called on the image it also triggers the click event handler for the image. The variable `swiping` keeps track of if the event was just a click or also a swipe.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch']);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.msg = function(event, msg) {
    swiping = true;
    alert(msg);
  }
});

// keep track of the user swiping. onYouTubeIframeAPIReady needs to occur outside of Angular. 
var swiping = false;

// Youtube related. 
document.getElementById('player').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('player-cover').addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (swiping) {
        swiping = false;
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById('player').style.display = 'block';
    player.playVideo();
});

// This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player) after the API code downloads.
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange }
    });
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PAUSED || event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        document.getElementById('player-cover').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('player').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('player-cover').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('player').display = 'block';
    }
}
```